# Is there a problem with my mongoid reference macros?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

The query Mongoid is executing does not make sense to me, and I think I must be defining a couple of things wrong.

But I do not know what the problem is

```
==Model Definition==
User
  references_many :questions_about, :class_name=>"Question", :inverse_of => :about_user

Question
  references_in :about_user, :class_name=>"User",:inverse_of => :questions_about
```

Console:

```
u=User.find("nazroll")
u.questions_about.map
db['questions'].find({"user_id"=>#010b}, {})
```

---

The correct query that should have been executed should be

```
db['questions'].find({"ABOUT_user_id"=>#010b}, {})
```

This is because I am defining the inverse of the :questions_about as :about_user

Any help rendered is greatly appreciated - tearing my head out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was actually because i was using an older version of mongoid, which was actually seriously buggy.

Upgrade to the latest version and all is fine

Answer (score 0):

The referenced_in macro, in this case, adds a field to your object called `about_user_id` and it is the `BSON::ObjectId` of the `User` being referenced.  The `references_many` macro is simply going to generate a query for that field using the `id` in the `User` instance you call it from.

In other words, you can think of `referenced_in` as a `belongs_to` and `references_many` as a `has_many`.

What exactly is the problem you are facing? Is it not running the correct query?

Comment: Hi paul! Yes, when i run=> u.questions_about.map, the query looks for the user field, instead of the about_user field. any idea why?